# Hidden words puzzle

Tags: word, visual, word-search

There are many words hidden inside this puzzle. Find them all.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found 29 words:

> HORIZONTAL
>
> 1 RAT
>   2 RATS
>   3 OR
>   4 CELL
>   5 IN
>   6 BUS
>
> VERTICAL
>
> 7 TAG
>   8 AGO
>   9 UP
>   10 COW
>   11 OWL
>   12 LAW
>
> HORIZONTAL BACKWARDS
>
> 13 ROUTE
>   14 LEAN
>   15 SO
>   16 SUB
>
> VERTICAL BACKWARDS
>
> 17 GATE
>   18 HOST
>   19 IT
>   20 KID
>   21 TIE
>
> DIAGONAL RIGHT TO LEFT
>
> 22 TO
>   23 ON
>
> DIAGONAL LEFT TO RIGHT
>
> 24 CUP
>   25 LINK
>
> DIAGONAL RIGHT TO LEFT BACKWARDS
>
> 26 OLD
>   27 DIE
>
> DIAGONAL LEFT TO RIGHT BACKWARDS
>
> 28 BIG
>   29 TEN

Comment: Just glancing around, I also see rot13(gna obbx ebhgre bhgre).

Answer (score 2):

There are *a lot* of words, so I've ignored 2-letter words.
**Running total: 49 words**

Horizontal:

> In row 1, there's **RAT(S)** and **(S)TAR** (backwards) 
>  In row 2, there's **ORE** and **ROUTE(R)** containing **OUT(ER)** (backwards)
>  In row 4, there's **(TW)ICE** and **CELL**
>  In row 5, there's **(E)BOOK** and **BEN** (backwards)
>  In row 6, there's **TAN** and **LEAN** (backwards)
>  In row 9, there's **BUS** and **SUB** (backwards)

Vertical:

> In column A, there's **ROE**, **AGO**, **TAG**, and **GATE**
>  In column B, there's **HOST** 
>  In column C, there's **TIE** 
>  In column D, there's **KID** 
>  In column E, there's **PUT** 
>  In column F, there's **COW**, **OWL**, and **TIE** (again) 
>  In column G, there's **LAW(S)** and **WALK**

Diagonal :

> **CUP** (F1-D3)
>  **PIN(G)** (D3-A6)
>  **POP** (G1-E3)
>  **WEB** (F3-D5)
>  **OLD** (E5-G3)
>  **BIG** (D5-B3)
>  **DOT** (G3-E1)
>  **NEW** (D6-B4)
>  **ANT** (C6-A4)
>  **NET(S)** and **TEN** (D6-G9)
>  **LONG** (F4-C7)
>  **LOAD** (G4-D7)
>  **LINK** (G6-D9)
>  **DAN** (D7-B5)

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer (not including 3 letter words, there are too many) :

format : WORD, row,column

6 letters words :

> ROUTER, 2-7

5 letters words :

> OUTER, 2-6
> ROUTE, 2-7
> TWICE, 4-1
> EBOOK, 5-3

4 letters words :

> RATS, 1-1
> STAR, 1-4
> COWL, 1-6
> ROUT, 2-7
> PING, 3-4
> CELL, 4-4
> LONG, 4-6
> LOAD, 4-7
> BOOK, 5-4
> GATE, 6-1
> NETS, 6-4
> LAWS, 6-7
> LEAN, 6-7
> LINK, 6-7
> WALK, 8-7
> HOST, 9-2

Obviously I missed words, please complete if you find more words.